# How to pass object of query params to Angular's router.navigate?

Tags: angular

I'm able to pass my query parameters to a router link as such:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/editinventoryitem',item.id]" [queryParams]="this.viewState">Edit</a> |
```

But when I try to redirect after an edit, and do this:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/inventoryitemdetails/' + this.editInventoryItemDetails.inventoryItem.id, this.viewState]);
```

I get this as the URL: `http://localhost:4200/index.html#/inventoryitemdetails/272049;searchTerm=;searchType=ManufacturerPN;deletedMode=InStock;viewMode=Compact;sortBy=ManufacturerPN;sortDir=ASC;pageIndex=1;resultsPerPage=25;warehouseID=0`

I could parse this to replace the first semi-colon with ?, and the rest with &, but I figure there has to be a way to pass the object the same way I do in a routerLink?

Edit: I worked around this by generating a click on the "Details" link like this:

```
document.getElementById('detailsLink')!.click();
```

...but it just seems wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Query params are added as a second parameter to navigate.

`router.navigate(['/url'],{queryParams: this.viewState});`

If `this.viewState` is already an object that is key/value pairs, for example:

```
this.viewState = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
}
```

The navigate would then produce the following url: `https://yourdomain.com/url?key1=value1&key2=value2`

Comment: Thanks, this worked as:  this.router.navigate(['/inventoryitemdetails/' + editInventoryResults.inventoryItem.id], { queryParams: this.viewState });  (Had to remove some {} from there...)

Comment: @pcalkins Shoot, sorry. I'll fix that in the answer. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: Looks correct now.